# Odoo file upload to "Log internal note"

Tags: javascript, python, file-upload, attachment, odoo-10

I would like to allow a user to drag and drop a file onto span defined in data/dragdrop.xml . This span appears in "Log internal note" section. The user should be able to drag and drop files on that "Log internal note" and files automatically upload and attach to that note (though that note is was not yet saved nor had any content in textarea). Basically the user should be able just drag and drop files on "Log internal note" and files get automatically uploaded and attached as internal notes.

Here is the code.

static/src/xml/dragdrop.xml has this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
   <t t-name="mail.chatter.ChatComposer" t-extend="mail.chatter.ChatComposer">
       <t t-jquery=".o_composer_attachments_list" t-operation="before">
            <span class="o_chatter_composer_info" id="chatter_drop_target">
                ~~~drag here~~~
            </span>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

views/data.xml has this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="lg_dragdrop" name="LG Drag Drop" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/dragdrop/static/src/js/dragdrop.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

static/src/js/dragdrop.js has this

```
odoo.define('dragdrop.dragdrop', function(require) {
    "use strict";


    var core = require('web.core');

    var Composer = require('mail.composer');

    var MailThread = core.form_widget_registry.get('mail_thread');

    var ExtendedBasicComposer = Composer.BasicComposer.include({
        ondrop: function(event) {
            var form_upload = document.querySelector('form.o_form_binary_form');

            if (null === form_upload) {
                return;
            }

            var e = event.originalEvent;

            document.querySelector('input.o_form_input_file').files = e.dataTransfer.files;
            this.$('form.o_form_binary_form').submit();
            for (var iterator = 0, file; file = e.dataTransfer.files[iterator]; iterator++) {
                if (file.name !== '') {
                    var filename = file.name.replace(/.*[\\\/]/,'');
                    // if the files exits for this answer, delete the file before upload
                    var attachments = [];
                    for (var i in this.get('attachment_ids')) {
                        if ((this.get('attachment_ids')[i].filename || this.get('attachment_ids')[i].name) === filename) {
                            if (this.get('attachment_ids')[i].upload) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            this.AttachmentDataSet.unlink([this.get('attachment_ids')[i].id]);
                        } else {
                            attachments.push(this.get('attachment_ids')[i]);
                        }
                    }                 
                }
            } 
        },
    });

    var NewChatterX = MailThread.include({
        on_open_composer_log_note: function(){
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var self = this;
            var c = self.composer;
            var main = document.querySelector('body');             
            $(document).on('drop', '#chatter_drop_target', function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                c.ondrop(event);
            });
            $(document).on('dragenter', '#chatter_drop_target', function(event){
                $('#chatter_drop_target').css({"color":"green"});
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            $(document).on('dragover', '#chatter_drop_target', function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            $(document).on('dragleave', '#chatter_drop_target', function(event){
                $('#chatter_drop_target').css({"color":"black"});
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        },
    }); 
});
```

I managed to catch drop event with that Javascript and upload but looks like the file get's uploaded twice.

In ir_attachments table for each uploaded file two records appear. Record's

```
+--------+------------------------------+------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------+--------------+
|   id   |          create_time         |        res_model       |  file_size |  res_id |                  store_fname                  |          mimetype          |     name    |  datas_fname |
+--------+------------------------------+------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| "4701" | "2018-08-03 11:20:48.709606" | "mail.compose.message" |          0 |       0 | ""                                            | "application/octet-stream" | "''"        | "''"         |
| "4700" | "2018-08-03 11:20:48.70132"  | "res.partner"          |       6568 |   19097 | "28/280cae7b8af0927d602e49a44c25f2cda4b6c2cb" | "application/octet-stream" | "file1.doc" | "file1.doc"  |
+--------+------------------------------+------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Uploaded file appears among model's attachments. But it is not really what is wanted because user wants the file to appear under "Internal notes" not under model's attachments. :/

What did I do wrong, how to fix upload?

Comment: The attachments seem to be associated with the main business object (`res.partner` in your case). Have you tried attaching it to the `mail.message` object that is/will be created for the internal note?

Comment: @miw I think it's default functionality: to attach drag-dropped files to the main business object. But when I upload from ExtendedBasicComposer (see js code in the question) it doesn't attach to any model. I don't know how to attach it to the model :/

Comment: I think that attachments of the `mail.message` objects appear directly with the message in the chatter. They can also/additionally be linked to the main business object, or the attachments of associated messages are dynamically added anyways, I'm not sure. For your case you'll have to work in the python code of `mail.compose.message`, where the `mail.message` is created. The empty attachment to `mail.compose.message` seems not directly useful.

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution for this ?

Comment: unfortunately no :(

Comment: okay, I'm also stuck in this.